# Android position buttons at bottom of screen

Tags: android, layout

Hi i'm having an issue with placing buttons at the bottom of the screen i have laid it out and in the graphical layout in eclipse it looks exactly how i want it but when i run it on the device the buttons both go to the very bottom of the screening the same position. so only one button is visible. does anyone know why this is or do you know how to place thing s at the bottom with a bit of padding?

heres what i have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background_credits"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fmbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fm"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fm"
        android:background="@drawable/visitphbtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

heres my code where i inflate this view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Check Preferences which sets UI
    setContentView(R.layout.singlenews);
    findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loadData();


       Button backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

        //Listening to button event
        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent previousScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(previousScreen);

            }
        });


}

public void loadData(){


    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    Log.v("lc", "infoname=" + name);




     if (name.equals(name1")) {

            NewsView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.infodetail,
                    null);

        TextView headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        headerText.setText("About name1"); 

        TextView mainText = (TextView) NewsView.findViewById(R.id.maintext);
        mainText.setText("name1");

        ImageView NewsImage = (ImageView)NewsView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        NewsImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_logo_evostik));


     }  

     if (name.equals("name2")) {

            NewsView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.infodetail,
                    null);

        TextView headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        headerText.setText("About name2"); 

        TextView mainText = (TextView) NewsView.findViewById(R.id.maintext);
        mainText.setText("name2");

        ImageView NewsImage = (ImageView)NewsView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        NewsImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_logo_pitchero));


     } 


     if (name.equals("name3")) {

            NewsView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.creditsdetail,
                    null);


            TextView headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_text);
            headerText.setText("name3"); 


            Button phbtn=(Button)NewsView.findViewById(R.id.ph);

            phbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            //Starting a new Intent
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.pitchero.com");
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                             startActivity(intent);


                        }
                    });

            Button fmbtn=(Button)NewsView.findViewById(R.id.fm);

            fmbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            //Starting a new Intent
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.fantasticmedia.co.uk/mobile/");
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                             startActivity(intent);


                        }
                    });




         } 




  ListView list = getListView();
  list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);



  Log.v("BGThread", "Filled results");

adapter = new MergeAdapter();

adapter.addView(NewsView);


setListAdapter(adapter);


}



}
```

Comment: Nothing looks out of place... Have you tried cleaning your project? From Eclipse go to Project > Clean > Select your project

Comment: i have tried cleaning it still same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some attributes mixed up.

In your second button don't add the '+' operator to id because it's making a new one. Just remove it and leave the '@'.

Remember '+' adds to id and '@' references it.

Comment: i have tried this ad it's still doing the same I'm really confused ps i didn't know that so thanks you have taught me something.

Comment: No worries. If it helps upvote it. If my answer worked than please accept it.

Comment: Also. RelativeLayouts don't take orientation so you can get rid of that

Answer (score 0):

I actually try your Layout in my project and the two buttons are correctly placed.

Are you sure you didn't make any other actions in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Well relative layout is relative to the other items inside the RelativeLayout container which is a ViewGroup.  So for example you could specify android:layout_leftOf="@+id/fm" in the description of pm.  If you want padding you might also expiriment with margin and padding like  inside the buttons.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" 
android:layout_leftOf="@+id/fm"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
```